# How to compare two "generic" array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var tstFrames = [TimeFrame]()
var tstFramesRefresh = [TimeFrame]()
```

Does anybody know how to compare them?

I found some examples adding array to `Set`, but `Set` doesn't have initializer which can accept this arraytype.. :(

The two array has almost the same instances of TimeFrame object  but tstFramesRefresh has one more which is not in tstFrames array i would get that one TimeFrame object.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if these arrays contain the same items?  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: sorry, i update my question..

Comment: You could a `Set`, like you suggested, you'd just need to make your type conform to `Hashable`.

Comment: thank you, could you please send me any tutorial how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say “compare” – do you mean equal, lexicographic comparison, or diff?  Sounds like you want a diff.

The set solution might look like this (assuming you want things in one not in the other, rather than the disjunction of the two):

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let b = [1,2]

Set(a).subtract(b)  // returns a set of {3}
```

Presumably your issue is that `TimeFrame` is not `Hashable`, hence it won’t work inside a set.

You could instead use `contains` to check if each element of `a` were a member of `b`.  Unfortunately this will be quite inefficient for large sets, since `contains` works in linear time so complexity will be `O(n^2)`.  But it’s easy to do:

```
func subtract<S: SequenceType, C: CollectionType, T: Equatable
    where C.Generator.Element == T, S.Generator.Element == T>
    (source: S, toSubtract: C) -> [S.Generator.Element] {
        return filter(source) { !contains(toSubtract, $0) }
}


subtract(a, b)  // returns [3]
```

More efficient solutions if your object were `Comparable` could use sorting or a tree structure.

If your objects aren’t `Equatable` either, you’d need a version that took a closure to check for equivalence:

```
func subtract<S: SequenceType, C: CollectionType>
    (source: S, toSubtract: C,
     isEquivalent: (S.Generator.Element, C.Generator.Element) -> Bool)
    -> [S.Generator.Element] {
        let x = filter(source) { elem in
            return !contains(toSubtract) { isEquivalent(elem,$0) }
        }
        return x
}

subtract(a, b) { $0 == $1 }
```

If you just want to check if they are equal, then `==` will do it – unless the objects aren’t equatable, in which case use the `equal` function that takes a comparator function:

```
// asuming these are classes and reference equality is reasonable thing to check
equal(tstFrames, tstFramesRefresh) { $0 === $1 }
```